# How to use Contact name if nickname is not present in bulk mail?

Tags: tokens, smarty

I need to send an email with Nickname as first preference, if that not present then use Contact name. Cant figure out what token to use?

I have tried this but seems not rendering correctly in email:

```
{capture assign=nickname}{contact.nick_name}{/capture} 
Dear {if $nickname}{contact.nick_name}{else}{contact.sort_name}{/if}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{capture assign=nickname}Tota{/capture} Dear {if $nickname}Tota{else}Mr. Tapash Datta{/if}
```

can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will need to turn on CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY in civicrm.settings.php to use smarty templating for conditional and more complex logic.

[image]

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: I seem to receive thousands of smarty error in drupal every time the email is viewed after enabling this option!! how can I fix it please? thanks